# The difference between django slice filter usages

Tags: python, django, django-templates, slice

I have a `myList` list with e.g. 5 elements, but I want to slice it in template by using command:

`{% for item in myList|slice:"3" %}`

or this command:

`{% for item in myList|slice:":3" %}`

What's the difference between `slice:"x"` and `slice:":x"`? (I don't have currently access to machine with django installed but I'm curious)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slice:"3"` and `slice:":x"` are both same as they will return first 3 elements from the list

but if you use `slice:"2:x"` then it will leave the 2 items from the first of the list and take from 3rd item till the number you mentioned in the x variable, its basically taking a part

Answer (score 3):

They produce same result:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> Template('{{xs|slice:"3"}} {{xs|slice:":3"}}').render(Context({
...    'xs': list(range(10))
... }))
u'[0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2]'
```

Django [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter internally use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) python function (or type).

> ```
> class slice(stop)   #  slice|"3" -> slice(3) -> slice(None, 3, None)
> class slice(start, stop[, step])  # slice|":3" -> slice(None, 3, None)
> ```